# Why can I access the non-public javax.swing.Box.Filler from another package?

Tags: java, inner-classes, protected, access-modifiers

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/nested-questions.html) in the Java tutorial got me very confused with question 2d. Looking at the Java documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html), it appears that the *static nested class* javax.swing.Box.AccessibleBox is protected, so it can be accessed in subclasses or in the same package; while the *inner class* javax.swing.Box.Filler has the default access modifier – package-protected, right? – so it can be accessed from the same package. However, just creating a simple class in a default Eclipse project:

```
package sandbox;
import javax.swing.Box;
public class ExternalClass {
    Box.Filler var1; // Fine?
    Box.AccessibleBox var2; // Compile error - not visible???
}
```

Why can I access Box.Filler; and if I can access that, then why can't I access Box.AccessibleBox, which, as protected, ought to be more visible than Box.Filler, which is package-protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `static`, but it is not `protected`. Javadocs omit the `public` modifier. If you look at the source, the complete class declaration for `Filler` is:

```
public static class Filler extends JComponent implements Accessible
```